# jQuery next in <TR> tag not working when TR collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with many rows, but each row need a help row, so they come in pairs.

For example

```
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Info 1</td>
   <td>Info 2</td>
   <td>Info 3</td>
   <td>Info 4</td>
   <td> <a>button more</a> </td>
</tr>
<!-- AND -->
<tr class="bottom-row">
   <td colspan="2">Info 5</td>
   <td colspan="2">Info 6</td>
   <td>Info 7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>OtherInfo 1</td>
   <td>OtherInfo 2</td>
   <td>OtherInfo 3</td>
   <td>OtherInfo 4</td>
   <td> <a>button more</a> </td>
</tr>
<!-- AND -->
<tr class="bottom-row">
   <td colspan="2">OtherInfo 5</td>
   <td colspan="2">OtherInfo 6</td>
   <td>OtherInfo 7</td>
</tr>
```

I want to click the bottom row is displayed, and click again to hide

I try use toggle of jQuery UI

```
    $(".btnMore").click(function(){
      $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next().toggle();        
  });
```

**This working perfect when the bottom rows are visible**, when i add `style="display:none"` stops working. Try also remove `style="display:none"` and add in load page `$(".bottom-row").hide();` but does not work either

that I can do?

Comment: hiding the row shouldn't have changed the functionality other than it being hidden first. Are you sure adding that style didn't cause invalid html due to a typo?

Comment: I see no elements with a class of btnMore to match your `$(".btnMore")` selector in your example.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem.Nothing in your code shows `display:none`

Comment: Working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/D3Uuy/4/

Comment: Thanks very much for your support, but, neither answer works for me, like my problem is my css but i can´t modify for enterpress rulez. Any mod can close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('table').on("click", ".btnMore", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PnUns/

Comment: Thanks very much for your support, but, neither answer works for me, like my problem is my css but i can´t modify for enterpress rulez. Any mod can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine when I try it, http://jsfiddle.net/LF7Ar/1/

```
// I added the hide from the beginning
$(".btnMore").click(function(){
  $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next().toggle();        
});
$('.bottom-row').hide();
```